# ESS indentation inside functions

Tags: indentation, ess

Indentation for R inside functions seems to be broken for pipes and '+'s:

```
f <- function(something){
    mutate(something, l="aaaa") %>%
        select(l) %>%
            str_replace("a", "A") %>%
                tolower()
}
```

The same happens with ggplot.

Is there anyway of fixing this behavior?

Comment: Your `ess-version` is probably older than 15.09. Newer versions default to proper indentation with `ess-offset-continued` set to `straight`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Please post this as an answer so I can mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ess-version` is probably older than 15.09. 15.09 came with a redesigned indentation engine and better defaults in `ess-styles-alist`. The relevant part for straight indentation is `ess-offset-continued` that is set to `straight` for all available styles.